# Div is not appearing when clicking on button

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, function

I am trying to create a Library (The Odin Project) and add information that is entered into my form to appear on my grid. I am stuck with my event listener and calling the function in order to make `bookCard` (my `library-container`) appear after clicking the submit button. Instead of my `bookCard` appearing in my grid, my overlay appears instead.

I am getting the following error in my console:

```
script.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'title')
    at new Book (script.js:4:23)
    at HTMLButtonElement.addBookToLibrary (script.js:18:15)
```

I looked up this issue and tried to define the form and now it is throwing an error for "title" Do I need to declare this in my js? Isn't declaring the form and then adding the class enough? What am I doing wrong here?

```js
// Library Functions //
class Book {
  constructor(title, author, pages, read) {
    this.title = form.title.value;
    this.author = form.author.value;
    this.pages = form.pages.value + 'pages';
    this.read = form.read.checked;
  }
}

//creates book from Book Constructor, adds to library
let myLibrary = [];
let newBook;

function addBookToLibrary() {
  event.preventDefault();
  popUpForm.style.display = 'none';
  newBook = new Book(title, author, pages);
  myLibrary.push(newBook);
  render();
  form.reset();
}

//Creates book visual in browser
function render() {
  const display = document.getElementById('#library-container');
  const books = document.querySelectorAll('.book');
  books.forEach(book => display.removeChild(book));

  for (let i = 0; i < myLibrary.length; i++) {
    createBook(myLibrary[i]);
  }
}

//
function createBook(item) {
  const bookDiv = document.createElement('div');
  const titleDiv = document.createElement('div');
  const authDiv = document.createElement('div');
  const pageDiv = document.createElement('div');


  bookDiv.classList.add('book');
  bookDiv.setAttribute('id', myLibrary.indexOf(item));

  titleDiv.textContent = item.title;
  titleDiv.classList.add('title');
  bookDiv.appendChild(titleDiv);

  authDiv.textContent = item.author;
  authDiv.classList.add('author');
  bookDiv.appendChild(authDiv);

  pageDiv.textContent = item.pages;
  pageDiv.classList.add('pages');
  bookDiv.appendChild(pageDiv);

  bookCard.style.display = "block";

};

// User interface //
const popUpForm = document.querySelector(".form-popup");
const button = document.querySelector("#addBook");
const overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
const booksGrid = document.getElementById('booksGrid');
const addBookForm = document.getElementById('addBookForm');
const bookCard = document.querySelector('library-container');
const form = document.querySelector("form-container");

// Form Pop Up function //
document.getElementById('invisibleDiv').onclick = function() {
  popUpForm.style.display = "none";
  overlay.style.display = "none";
};

button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  popUpForm.style.display = "block";
  overlay.style.display = "block";
});

const updateBooksGrid = () => {
  resetBooksGrid()
  for (let book of library.books) {
    createBook(book)
  }
};


// Card for grid function //

const addBtn = document.querySelector("#submit");
addBtn.addEventListener('click', addBookToLibrary);
```

```css
/*CSS RESET*/

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h1 {
  font-family: ohno-blazeface, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 8vh;
  color: #001D4A;
}

.head-box {
  background-color: #9DD1F1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 20vh;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #e0f3ff;
}

h2 {
  font-family: poppins, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 5vh;
  color: #001D4A;
}

h3 {
  font-family: ohno-blazeface, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 4vh;
  color: #001D4A;
}

button {
  height: 10vh;
  width: 20vh;
  min-width: 20vh;
  min-height: 10vh;
  font-size: 3vh;
  background-color: #27476E;
  border-radius: 22px;
  border-style: none;
  font-family: poppins, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: normal;
  color: #ffffff;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #192c44;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #d0edff, #9DD1F1) no-repeat;
}

.body-box {
  margin: 3vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}


/* The pop up form - hidden by default */

.form-popup {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 9;
}

.form-content {
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 30vh;
  height: auto;
  border: 3px solid #001D4A;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #9DD1F1;
  gap: 10px;
}

.form-container {
  min-width: 20vh;
  min-height: 50vh;
}

.isRead {
  display: flex;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 2px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

label {
  font-family: poppins, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 2.5vh;
}

input {
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 4px;
  background-color: #d0edff;
  border: none;
  font-family: poppins, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 2.5vh;
}

#submit {
  margin-top: 4px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 15px;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: none;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  width: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
}

#invisibleDiv {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.books-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(300px, 1fr));
}

#library-container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #d0edff;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!----------Font Below ---------------->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/jmq2vxa.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/open-book.png" />
  <title>My Library</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="head-box">
    <h1>My Library</h1>
  </div>
  <main class="main-container">
    <div class="body-box">
      <button id="addBook">Add Book</button>
    </div>
    <div class="books-grid" id="booksGrid"></div>
    <div class="library-container" id="library-container"></div>
  </main>
  <!-----Form information----->
  <div class="form-popup">
    <div class="form-content" <form action="example.com/path" class="form-container" id="popUpForm">
      <h3>add new book</h3>
      <input class="input" type="text" id="title" placeholder="Title" required maxlength="100">
      <input type="author" id="author" placeholder="Author" required maxlength="100">
      <input type="number" id="pages" placeholder="Pages" required max="10000">
      <div class="isRead">
        <label for="readOption">Have you read it?</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="readOption" name="readOption">
      </div>
      <button class="btn submit" type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="overlay"></div>
  <div id="invisibleDiv"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: In fact, there is a bunch of errors because of typos, about this error is produced by `form` because you miss the dot `.` before `form-container`, so it should be `const form = document.querySelector(".form-container");`

Answer (score -1):

In your function updateBooksGrid inside the for loop the array library.books is never defined. I believe you should put the "MyLibrary" array there? Maybe this will fix your error.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).